# How do I change TextBox.Text without losing the binding in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, input, binding

I have a text box which is bound to a class property

```
 <TextBox x:Name="TradeTextBox" 
    Text="{Binding Path=Entier,
                   Mode=TwoWay,
                   NotifyOnValidationError=True,
                   ValidatesOnExceptions=True,
                   UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"/>
```

and here is my property:

```
private string _entier;
public string Entier
        {
            get { return _entier; }
            set
            {
                if (!Regex.IsMatch(Entier.Trim(), NumberPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
                    throw new ArgumentException("can only have numbers not characters");
                _entier = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Entier");
            }
        }
```

As you can see, I am using exception validation and notify property changed
Now, my problem is: when I try to initialize `textBox.Text` from main class constructor, the text is displaying as empty...

I tried to do this, but some how it doesn't work :

```
 public MyClass()
    {
        TradeTextBox.Text = "30";
        TradeTextBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
    }
```

Can you help me? Please figure out why the `textBox.text` is not set to "30" when I run the application?

Comment: You should just update the thing that is being bound, not the text box. The whole point of binding is by updating the underlying value the text box should get updated.

Answer (score 2):

I mean it looks likes your setting the text to 30 then getting the value from your source, which is not 30.

Why not make your source value 30?

EDIT- Depending on wherever your source file it it would just be

sourcevalue = textbox.text

I could provide a better answer if you told me more about your source.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what if i want to make a condition : like, if checkBox1 is Chekecd, i want the textbox.tex="30" else textBox.Text="10"... is there any way to update textBox source this way ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few ways to set a default value:

declaratively in the xaml(-binding):

```
<TextBox x:Name="TradeTextBox" 
    Text="{Binding Path=Entier,
                   TargetNullValue='30',
                   Mode=TwoWay,
                   NotifyOnValidationError=True,
                   ValidatesOnExceptions=True,
                   UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"/>
```

As a default for the Viewmodel property:

```
private string _entier = "30";
public string Entier
    {
        get { return _entier; }
        set
        {
            if (!Regex.IsMatch(Entier.Trim(), NumberPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
                throw new ArgumentException("can only have numbers not characters");
            _entier = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Entier");
        }
    }
```

And finally... with some code (that won't touch the existing binding, but I'm not sure if this is really necessary):

```
public MyClass()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
public void CheckBoxChecked()
{
    SetBinding(TagProperty, new Binding("Text"){Source=TradeTextBox, Mode=TwoWay});
    Tag="30";
}
```